# Develop google home Actions and handled by AWS Node.js server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, google-home

Hi I want to make a simple google home Action, which will be controlling a LED of my development board. But I want to host data routing and handling by AWS. I have MQTT communication running between AWS server and the development board.

I am planning to deploy a Node.js server in AWS Elastic Beanstalk or Elastic computer cloud.

But I am not sure how to connect the request make on Google Home to the AWS service. Is there good documentation for this? 
If possible I want to know the options with "DialogFlow" and with "Actions API".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fulfillment for both Dialogflow and the Actions API goes through a webhook that you define. This will need to be an HTTPS server, with a valid non-self-signed SSL certificate, available at a public IP address. You can run this on EC2 in a variety of configurations - whatever works best for you.

On the Node.js side, most application servers are using something like Express.js to handle some routing and middleware processing. The [libraries from Google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google) assume that you'll be passed a `request` and a `response` object that have been processed using Express.js and through the [express body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to turn the JSON HTTPS body into a Javascript object. However, you don't need to use these libraries if you don't want - you just need to parse and respond with JSON.